# How jquery function is calling?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery,but stuck-up at some problem.Please any one can tell me, which is the block of code in following code, which is calling 'hideAllMessages' function. On clicking on ('Info','Error','Warning','Success')

,it is calling `hideAllMessages` function, but not able to understand which is the block of code,who is doing this task.

**[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/eGeB7/1/)**

As there is no javascript 'onclick' function present in following line.

```
<li><a href="#" class="trigger info-trigger">Info</a></li>
```

Actually i want to ask flow of code after clicking of ('Info','Error','Warning','Success').

Comment: Looks like "Find the rabbit from the picture of forest below and mark it with a <pre> tag" :) jQuery uses 'click' function on an element like $(<css=selector>).click(function(){}) instead of usual onclick.

Comment: You should avoid mixing inline event handlers like `onclick="naughty()"` with markup and instead attach event handlers like `$('.trigger').click(nice);` That last part is without the `()` so you give the `$.click()` method a reference to the function `function nice(){}`, otherwise you call it right away instead of setting the handler to run `nice()` on event firing.

Answer (score 0):

First your `hideAllMessages();` called when document is ready from jquery.

After then your `showMessage(myMessages[i]);` is called and `hideAllMessages();` is again used as it is in your `showMessage()` .

Answer (score 0):

Try `Ctrl+F` :-) You seem to have overlooked the following part of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("ready function called");
    // Initially, hide them all
    hideAllMessages();
    ...
```

Also, it is called from the click-handler installed by the `showMessage`-function:

```
$('.'+ type +'-trigger').click(function(){
    hideAllMessages();                  
    $('.'+type).animate({top:"0"}, 500);
});
```

There does not need to be a `onclick` attribute in the HTML, the usual way to [install event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) is purely a DOM task ([jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

jQuery is works in similiar ways to javascript.

A function will not be 'activated' unless called.

Looking through your code, you'll realise that there is a

```
$(document).ready(function{
    //insert code here
});
```

the above code will run the moment your page loads, from up to down.

After this piece of code finished running, your jQuery will stop running.

But you'll also come to realise that each of your "li"s has a 'trigger' function, which will activate the show-message function, displaying its respective messages.

Thats how your piece of code works

Edit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("ready function called");

     // Initially, hide them all
     hideAllMessages();

     // Show message
     for(var i=0;i<myMessages.length;i++)
     {
        showMessage(myMessages[i]);
     }
```

When the page is loaded, the "showMessage function is called 4 times. (as you can see, there are 4 popup messages when the page loads.)

Each time the showMessage function is called, it is sent a certain "type". Which includes info, error, etc.

```
function showMessage(type)
{
alert("showMessage function called");
$('.'+ type +'-trigger').click(function(){
      hideAllMessages();                  
      $('.'+type).animate({top:"0"}, 500);
});
}
```

However in each of these showMessage functions, nothing is actually running, the function only runs when the "button" is clicked.

```
$('.info-trigger'.click(function(){
```

in the above example, the 'info' type is being passed into the showMessage function, which will replace the 'type', hence generating the info-trigger.

When the info button is clicked, the function will first run the hideMessage function, and then run the animate function.

Hope this explains.

Comment: watch in firebug `script` panel and debug bypause and press **F11** : [`read this`](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel)

Comment: Thanks He Hui, I am not able to understand "each of your "li"s has a 'trigger' function, which will activate the show-message function,"Can u elaborate more this line?.........Can u tell me "Where is trigger function"?... How my each of li tag is activating show-message function?

Comment: Rest of things i know.....that "$(document).ready(function{//insert code here});" is called once the DOM is ready? which is calling hideAllMessages function and then showMessages function?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready/ pls refer to this link to understand the .ready() function